# Does the episode 4 of Dark Matter contain... a Reliant Robin?

Tags: dark-matter

Weird question alert.

These are two screenshots from [episode 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Matter_(TV_series)#Season_1_.282015.29) of [Dark Matter](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4159076/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl) (timestamp: from 10m32s - 10m34s).

[image: Dark Matter - Reliant Robin 1?]

[image: Dark Matter - Reliant Robin 2?]

This looks to me just like the [Reliant Robin](https://www.google.com/search?q=reliant+robin) [car](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliant_Robin)!

[image: Reliant Robin, similar angle, from http://www.carandclassic.co.uk/uploads/cars/reliant/3075727.jpg]

Apart from the shape, it also appears to have three wheels and even wing mirrors:

[image: Seriously, wing mirrors?]

Questions:

1. Is this really a Reliant Robin (or at least inspired by it)?
2. If so, what is the real world reason?
3. I'll give a bounty to anyone who can provide an *in-universe* reason, because it would be a spectacular find.

Comment: It would be a Reliant Robin, NOT a Robin Reliant.

Comment: @Chenmunka: thanks, fixed.

Comment: Other than three wheels and wing mirrors, I don't see any resemblance in the body style. It could well be some other production 3-wheeler, though. SFF TV and movies often use cars from non-U.S/Canada/Britain as stand-ins for alien cars.

Comment: @JoeL.: I don't think the still photos really do the car justice... It is clearer in the video.

Comment: The rear is very different to the Robin, in the sahpe of the window and the position of taillights, not to mention some kind of panel. No reason that it couldn't be *built* on a Reliant chassis and made for the series, is there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a [Xap Zebra](http://www.curbsideclassic.com/curbside-classics-asian/curbside-classic-zap-xebra-the-assassination/), cheap Chinese-made electric car from the mid 00s, seems fairly unmodified/disguised as well:

[image]

They most likely used it as it looks fairly futuristic, and most people will have never seen one in the real world.

Comment: Fantastic, how did you 1. come by this question and 2. work this out?

Comment: 1: was searching through old questions to see if there were any i could help with

Comment: 2; I remembered seeing an electric car which looked very much like the one in question in the past (5 doors, three wheels, quite unusual really) quick search and I found the article again.

Comment: Cool, thanks very much + congrats on getting it accepted.